# Combining outputs of multiple queries into one

Tags: mysql

```
1.select col1,col2 from table1 where condition1=<<value1>>
UNION ALL 
select col1,col2 from table2 condition1=<<value2>>;

2. `select col1 from table3;`

3. I need to write the 3rd query where i need the output of col1,col2 from table1 based on the col1 (sort based on col1 from table3).
```

I can do this way

```
create table as temp_table as
select col1,col2 from table1 where condition1=<<value1>>
UNION ALL 
select col1,col2 from table2 condition1=<<value2>>;

SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2
FROM temp_table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t2 ON t1.col2=t2.col2
order by t2.col1;
```

I want in a single query(in mysql ) & not using temp table.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the unioned result as subselect.

Comment: select SELECT col1,col2
FROM
(select col1,col2 from table1 where condition1=<<value1>>
UNION ALL 
select col1,col2 from table2 condition1=<<value2>>) sub
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON sub.col2=t3.col2
order by t3.col1;

Answer (score 2):

Look into [subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html). They're kind of like a temporary table that only exists while the query is running.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select T.A, T.B from

(select col1 as A,col2 as B from table1 where condition1=<<value1>>
UNION ALL 
select col1,col2 from table2 condition1=<<value2>>) as T,
table3 as T2
where T.A = T2.col1

order by t2.col1
```